# Printing arrays to screen in React Native

Tags: ios, arrays, react-native

I simply want to print a couple of arrays on screen in my React Native iOS app. Right now nothing is showing up on screen. console.logs after the for loop show that the arrays have the data they are supposed to have, but it is not reflected on screen. How do I render again after the fetch call has loaded? Here's my code:

```
'use unique'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView
} from 'react-native';

import api from './apicall';

class APIRequest extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      users: [],
      id: [],
      type: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {

      api.getData()
        .then((res) => {
          this.setState({
            users: res
          })
          for (var i = 0; i < this.state.users.length; i++) {
            this.state.id.push(this.state.users[i].id);
            this.state.type.push(this.state.users[i].type);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
          {this.state.id}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.state.id.push(this.state.users[i].id);
this.state.type.push(this.state.users[i].type);
```

That's the wrong way to set new state. You should do the following:

```
var idArray = [];
var typeArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.users.length; i++) {
  idArray.push(this.state.users[i].id);
  typeArray.push(this.state.users[i].type);
}
this.setState({id: idArray});
```